# i am trying to open a url in default web browser. But it is not responding. it does not opening default web browser

Tags: ios, swift

Completion block returns the false value. I'm just trying to open www.google.com. Here is my code. Xcode version 9.4.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "www.google.com")!, options: [ : ]) 
 { (success) in

debugPrint(success)

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with including "http://" in the url?

Answer (score 0):

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
}
```

Add https or http before URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `HTTPS`.
Your code is fine but needs to add `https`

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!, options: [ : ]) 
 { (success) in

debugPrint(success)

}
```